# Getting a "Run time error - 13 , type mismatch" error while getting a row from an array

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get the single row from a 2d array and also the position of a element in a array.

I am using the below expression for them respectively but getting a type mismatch error.

```
arr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Arra1, 1, 0) - to get a row from a array

pos = Application.Match(MatchedServiceNumber, Array1, False)
```

... to get a position of a element inside a array

Please help

Comment: Could you post a more complete code with declaration of the variables?

Comment: Its a big code , but for declaration I am using , Dim Array1 as variant. I mainly want to get the whole row from a 2d array. I will specify the index of the row as input and need to get that whole row in an array.

Comment: Post a [mcve] .

Comment: Dim 1dArray as variant ,1dArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Array2d, 1, 0). Here I am getting a row that means 1d array from a 2darray. But getting the error. Can you check if there is something wrong with an expression?

Comment: `arr1` is first row of `Arra1` but then you are matching `Array1` ?